# heroku javascript ajax post not returning anything

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, heroku

I'm trying to do a ajax post to a heroku server app and have the app return a response to the client web page (on a different server).

It works just fine if I test it locally (using localhost) but when I push to heroku, I get no response.

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser()).post('/', function(req, res){
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With").header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
res.end("test");
});

    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port);
```

**client-side js:**

```
$.post("http://myapp-name-here.heroku.com", {query: "anything", val: "something"},
function(data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

Edited in:

When I open the client-side html page, when it makes the post request, it gets the status "canceled" after a couple of seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the request reach the server? Can you add a `console.log()` on the server side? Are you sure the url leads to the proper Heroku app?

Comment: I'm a little new to heroku. I can put a console.log() in the app.js but I don't know how I can read that from heroku.

Comment: run `heroku logs` in the application directory. This will also show you if the app is running. If you just created the app, it may take a while for the domain name to point to the right IP.

Comment: okay, it doesn't seem to get inside here: app.use(express.bodyParser()).post('/', function(req, res){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myapp-name-here.heroku.com` is no longer supported, try `myapp-name-here.herokuapp.com`

Comment: I couldn't believe this was actually the reason. I have another heroku app that works just fine using .heroku.com. Have been scratching my head for hours, so I appreciate it.